# Input in *ngFor binds to same value for all inputs

Tags: angular, ngfor

I faced a problem in the angular 7 in ngFor loop.
I want to add a  value of the probability of each month
and the result must displayed in the expected  cell of the table  of that month;
but when I add the probability value, the same result is displayed for all the months
when I change the probability of any month the same result appears in all the fields of the column `amountPrev`.

This is my html code:

```html
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table class="styled-table" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr height="50">
        <th align="center" width="150">&nbsp;</th>
        <td align="center" width="150" colspan="5" *ngFor="let item of listMoisAnnee">{{item}}</td>

      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr height="50">
        <td align="center" width="150" style="background-color:#d4cdc94f;">&nbsp;</td>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of listMoisAnnee">
          <td align="center" width="150" style="background-color:#d4cdc94f;">Valeur origine</td>
          <td align="center" width="150" style="background-color:#d4cdc94f;">Probabilité en(%)</td>
          <td align="center" width="150" style="background-color:#d4cdc94f;">Montant Prevu</td>
          <td align="center" width="150" style="background-color:#d4cdc94f;">Tva déductible/immo </td>
          <td align="center" width="150" style="background-color:#d4cdc94f;">TTC </td>

        </ng-container>
      </tr>

      <tr height="50" *ngFor="let item of listEcheances;let parentIndex=index; trackBy:trackByIndex ">
        <th>{{item.Intitule}}</th>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let d of datee">
          <td>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let subItem  of item.value;"><label 
                *ngIf="subItem.date === d ">{{subItem.valeurOrigine}}</label></ng-container>
          </td>
          <td>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let subItem  of item.value; ">
              <input id="k" *ngIf="subItem.date === d " type="number"
                [ngModel]="probaReal[parentIndex]" 
                (ngModelChange)="calcul([subItem.valeurOrigine][parentIndex],$event)"
                 style="border: none;">
            </ng-container>
          </td>
          
          <td>
            
            <ng-container *ngFor="let subItem  of item.value;let k =index">
              <input *ngIf="subItem.date === d " type="number" 
              [ngModel]="montantPrev[parentIndex]" style="border: none;">
            </ng-container>
          </td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>


        </ng-container>

      </tr>



    </tbody>

  </table>


</div>
```

This my .ts code:

```js
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  
  dateDebut = "Jan-2021"
  dateFin = "Dec-2021";

  listMoisAnnee=["Janvier-2021","Février-2021","Mars-2021"]
  datee=["2021-01","2021-02","2021-03"]
  listEcheances = []
  sousListEcheances = []
  probaReal: any = [];
  montantPrev=[]
  data={
    "Pc": [
        {
            "idEch": 1,
            "intitule": "Pc",
            "date": "2021-01",
            "year": 2021,
            "month": "JANUARY",
            "valeurOrigine": 1.5E7
        },
        {
            "idEch": 2,
            "intitule": "Pc",
            "date": "2021-02",
            "year": 2021,
            "month": "FEBRUARY",
            "valeurOrigine": 1.5E7
        },
        {
            "idEch": 3,
            "intitule": "Pc",
            "date": "2021-03",
            "year": 2021,
            "month": "MARCH",
            "valeurOrigine": 7.0E7
        }
    ],
    "XXX": [
        {
            "idEch": 10,
            "intitule": "XXX",
            "date": "2021-02",
            "year": 2021,
            "month": "FEBRUARY",
            "valeurOrigine": 5000000.0
        },
        {
            "idEch": 11,
            "intitule": "XXX",
            "date": "2021-03",
            "year": 2021,
            "month": "MARCH",
            "valeurOrigine": 5000000.0
        }
    ]
    
}

  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getListEcheance(this.dateDebut,this.dateFin)
  }

  getListEcheance(dateDebut, dateFin) {
        this.listEcheances = Object.keys(this.data).map(key => ({ Intitule: key, value: this.data[key] }));
  }

 
 calcul(item,proba) {
      this.datee.forEach((i,k)=>{
        this.montantPrev[k]=(proba * item)/100
        console.log(this.montantPrev[k])
        
      })
  }
  trackByIndex(index: number, value: number) {
    return index;
    }



}


Could anyone tell me what is the mistake that I'm making?
```

Comment: You should share the data values ​​and more space in your code. I do not get an error in a structure similar to yours and that I have built.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wfzyfy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: i've edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you always write the same value of the variable `montantPrev`. The `parentIndex` variable that you use as index will always come to `0`, but you are trying to change a stitched array. For this reason, you should choose a unique value such as `idEch`.

change your first input like this :

```
            <input id="k_{{subItem.idEch}}" *ngIf="subItem.date === d " type="number"
                [ngModel]="probaReal[subItem.idEch]"
                (ngModelChange)="calcul(subItem.valeurOrigine, subItem.idEch,$event)"
                 style="border: none;">
```

change your second input like this :

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let subItem  of item.value;let k =index">
            <input *ngIf="subItem.date === d " type="number"
            id="d_{{subItem.idEch}}"
              [ngModel]="montantPrev[subItem.idEch]" style="border: none;">
          </ng-container>
```

Change your `calcul` method like this :

```
calcul(item, index, newValue) {
    this.montantPrev[index] = (newValue * item) / 100;
    console.log(this.montantPrev);
  }
```

[This](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wfzyfy?file=src/app/app.component.ts) is working demo.

Comment: thanks a lot for your effort 
@Onur Özkır